# How to appy cascade delete using model yii

Tags: php, yii

I have 3 tables which depend on each other.

```
1st level = partner_company
2nd level = partner
3rd level =  partner_deals
```

In 1st level have "`id`".
2nd level have "`company_id`" which is foreign key of partner_company "`id`".
3rd level have "`partner_id`" which is foreign key of partner table (2nd level) "`id`".

=> now I want to add functionality of any user delete company which have `id = 1` then also delete all record from 2nd level table and 3rd level company.

=> If admin delete record from partner (2nd level) which have `id = 1` then delete record from partner_deals (3rd level) which have `partner_id = 1`.

so can anyone please help me to add this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you have done so far.

Comment: Why not define the cascade delete for the relations in the database itself? Or don't you have the rights to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can override `beforeDelete` so that it will delete first the records that are dependent.

In your `partner_company` model make a relation to `partner` model

```
public function getPartner(){
  return $this->hasOne(Partner::className(), ['id' => 'company_id']);
}

public function beforeDelete() {
  $this->partner->delete();

  // call the parent implementation so that this event is raise properly
  return parent::beforeDelete();
}
```

Do the same to the other two models `partner` and `partner_deals`